# How to print a multi-lined string into a message box?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, newline, messagebox

I am trying to print a 'last receipt' from a customer in which i have stored into a sting variable called prevRecpt.

I want to be able to press a button (btnLastReceipt) and this will display this sting in a message box.

Is this possible? As I have already tried and ended up with the message box only showing the first line?

```
        prevRcpt = "--------------------Butlers Cinemas--------------------" &     Environment.NewLine
        prevRcpt = prevRcpt & tbTime.Text & Environment.NewLine
        prevRcpt = prevRcpt + "Operator: " + tbUser.Text & Environment.NewLine
        prevRcpt = prevRcpt + Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine + "-------------------------------------------------------"
        prevRcpt = prevRcpt + "Total Spent: £" + tbTotal.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine
        prevRcpt = prevRcpt + shoppingCart.Text + Environment.NewLine
        prevRcpt = "--------------------Butlers Cinemas--------------------" & Environment.NewLine
```

This is the code for building up the string.

Comment: What are you using to stipulate a new line in your string lastReceipt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>Have you tried concatenating `Environment.NewLine` anywhere in your string?</s>

Now that I can see your code, it seems that your last line should be this instead:

```
prevRcpt = prevRcpt & "--------------------Butlers Cinemas--------------------" & Environment.NewLine
```

That being said, you need to be aware than in the event of a very long string, the message box could size out of screen bounds, so you may want to use something else than `MessageBox`. If possible, make your own dialog form, make its default size convenient for most scenarios and use a scrollable text zone within it. A readonly `TextBox` with `Multiline` property set to `True` would not only be scrollable, but *also* allow the end user to copy the content in the clipboard. It may make the user's experience a lot better.

I should also mention that [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and a few constants could help you make this code a lot cleaner:

```
Const headerOrFooter As String = "--------------------Butlers Cinemas--------------------"
Const separator As String = "-------------------------------------------------------"

Dim b As New Text.StringBuilder()

b.AppendLine(headerOrFooter)
b.AppendLine(tbTime.Text)
b.AppendFormat("Operator: {0}", tbUser.Text)
b.AppendLine()
b.AppendLine()
b.AppendLine()
b.AppendLine(separator)
b.AppendFormat("Total Spent: £{0}", tbTotal.Text)
b.AppendLine()
b.AppendLine(shoppingCart.Text)
b.AppendLine(headerOrFooter)

prevRcpt = b.ToString()
```

Comment: And even more useful, a form where you can actually select/copy the text!

Comment: I've done the Environment.NewLine throughout to the string to spread it out. However,I haven't used Visual Studio enough to come across dialog forms? How do they work exactly?

Comment: @JohannBlais heh, I was just adding that by the time you posted your comment. :)

Comment: @jbutler483 please show how you are building up your string (edit your original post).

Comment: @jbutler483 also what I refer to as a *dialog form* is just a custom form like any others you may have done in the past, only you will want to show this one using the `ShowDialog` method.

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit of a mess :S

Comment: @Crono I can't believe I didn't spot that, I feel a right tit now. But thanks for the help, i'll have a look into the scrollable textbox instead. As you can probably tell, i'm still pretty green when it comes to coding :S

Comment: @jbutler483 Don't be ashamed, friend, we've all been there (and from time to time we *still* are). ;) Please do not forget to mark your question as answered. Thanks and happy coding!